# Make a row selected after adding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want it so that when I add a row to a datatable, that row will be selected (highlighted). So I remove the selected class from the currently selected row, but I don't know how to add the selected class to the new row.

Removes selected class from currently selected row.

```
$('#rListTable tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

Adds new row to table.

```
aTable.row.add(data.analysis).draw(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `table.row.add()` returns an instance of the row you have just added. So to style that row you just need to select it like:

```
var rowAdded = aTable.row.add(data.analysis).draw(false);
$(rowAdded).addClass('selected');
```

Or you can simply do:

```
aTable.row.add(data.analysis).draw(false).nodes().to$().addClass('selected');
```

You can check the [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())

Comment: Thanks, I understand this is the correct way of doing this but for some reason it's not working in my case. Nothing is being highlighted. Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: I corrected a typo on the end of my answer, could it be that? is there any kind of console error?

Comment: I just edited the answer try doing `aTable.row.add(data.analysis).draw(false).nodes().to$().addClass('selected');`

Answer (score 0):

Add a row and get its newly created node to highlight that it was newly added:

```
 var rowNode = aTable.row.add(data.analysis).draw(false); //This will add the row 
 $( rowNode ).addClass('selected'); //This will highlight that newly added row
```

Regards